# Android paypal sdk 2.43 intergration

Tags: android, paypal, payment

Good night developers,

Credit Card Payment

I have some problem with configuring paypal credit card payment and my best priority is let application user to enter cardholder's name.

but paypal sdk does not require any cardholder's name as default

I presume cardholder's name field could be generated by PaypalConfiguration

What I had done with this class is below.

```
config = new PayPalConfiguration()
                .environment(PayPalAPI.PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT)
                .rememberUser(false)
                .clientId(this.getString(R.string.paypal_client_id));
```

I have been searching how to add card holder's name into this class but I could not find anything..

Payment Method

My second purpose is to detect which payment method end-user decided, by Paypal ID or Credit card to upload to our server in order to issue receipt

I also searched how to detect and found to use REST API to get payment method.

but this process requires to use OAuth 2.0 and I do not think I could find a proper way to send to server by OAuth 2.0 protocol

Thank you in advance and have a nice day :)

Comment: I dont know about holder's name but you can get issue receipt from its response after payment done,from  onActivityResult.

Comment: #Nisarg Thank you for your comment, and you are right, I could get the receipt from onActivityResult, but data returned from onActivityResult should be more clear, the values returned from it does not show any data I mentioned from my post

Comment: yea it will, let me know if you find any problem understanding its response